# will this circuit work as intented?

Tags: fluid-pump

My question is will the following circuit work as an automatic pump control.
sorry for the terrible design.

if i connect the analogue pressure sensor in the primary connection in the circuit after a motorized pump,and the secondary sensor before the pump, and the motor leads between the motor and the mains ,will the following happen?[image]

1-if the difference between the pressure at each side of the pump is lower than a pre-set value by pot 1(which means someone opened the tab), then the relay should close the circuit ,leading to the pump being run.
2-if the difference between the pressure at each side of the pump is higher than a pre-set value by pot 0(which means someone closed the tab), then the relay should open the circuit ,leading to the pump shutting off.

please don't flame me for a major design and just point it out.

**If It Would Work can someone help me make a breaboard design.**

i need to measure the difference between pressures as sometimes the water increases it's pressure or decreases it.
also thanks in advance and sorry for improper formatting and language,still new to the forum.

Comment: Hello and welcome to EE.SE. This looks like a bang-bang control for the pump, using a upper and lower setpoint. You may get the same result but simpler using a "Schmitt Trigger" with adjustable hysteresis using the pots (google it) on the output of your differential op-amp output. The breadboard will need at least a 5V supply for the logic chips, and maybe a -5V for the diff-amp negative supply, depending how your pressure sensor actually provides signal. Can you tell us how the pressure sensors work? They just provide a linear voltage between 0->V_supply?

Comment: The hysteresis would not be very adjustable, but rather the thresholds are adjustable/able to be designed into it, and you only need the single schmitt trigger. The output of the Schmitt trigger would go straight to the FET (maybe through another unity gain buffer opamp...)

Comment: the sensor provides linear voltage between 0-> vcc from 0 psi to about 90 psi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks plausible. 1K is probably a bit low for the resistors on your diffamp. Try 10K or 20K. Don't expect it to work too close to the supply rail(s) even with rail-to-rail input and output amplifiers/comparators. You may wish to restrict the range of adjustment of S and R pots to keep within the common mode range of the parts, and perhaps reduce the gain of the amplifier somewhat, and choose deliberately whether you want the pot range to exceed the possible output limits of the diffamp or not.

Also, note that you will have no signal at all if the secondary sensor is greater than the primary, because the output voltage would have to be negative. Maybe that's of no concern to you.

There is also no guaranteed gap between S and R, in fact you can set the pots so they overlap, so you should consider what that means- typically one or the other output will "win" on the RS flip-flop- for example on the 74HC74, both the Q and /Q outputs go high when both /S and /R are active. It wouldn't be too hard to buffer the wiper from one pot and use it to feed the element on the other pot if that made more sense.

Edit: You could use something like this to prevent the two settings from overlapping by much. If you added a diode between the buffer amplifier and the pot, you would guarantee a gap of 600mV or so between on and off, over most of the range.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQGY3C.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: the secondary sensor will never be higher

Comment: can you please explain more as i have very little enginering background

Comment: so it will work if i use 20k resistors and use a buffer ?

Comment: can you please help me make a breadboard design by suggesting components